# Per-thread instance object in TPL Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, task-parallel-library

Is there a TPL syntax which allows you to inject objects from pool into tasks so that one object is only used by one thread at once? Or even better - only used by the same once thread?

### Usage example

Assume I want to create 10 threads which open 10 files: `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt` ... `10.txt` and write 500 000 consequent numbers randomly to these files.

I can do this:

```
ConcurrentQueue<int> objs = new ConcurrentQueue<int>(); // 500000 numbers go here
Task[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i =>
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            using (var f = File.Open($"{i}.txt"))
            {
                using (var wr = StreamWriter(f))
                {
                    while (objs.TryDequeue(out int obj))
                    {
                        wr.WriteLine(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

However, is it possible to provide the same behaviour without utilizing concurrent collections, just with TPL?

Comment: You know about ThreadLocal<T>?

Comment: Why not *tune* `ForEach` with `ParallelOptions`? `Parallel.ForEach(objs, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, o => {...});` Another possibility is Parallel Linq: `objs.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(4).ForAll(o = > ...);`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a database performance problem X and think that you'll fix it by executing a lot of connections in parallel (Y). When that fails, you ask about Y.  Executing multiple database queries in parallel is *NOT* going to fix any performance problems. It can easily make them worse though. ORMs are *not* meant to handle a lot of data.

Comment: And finally, ORMs are *neither* reporting tools nor bulk import tools. They can work with single object graphs, but not multiple rows. What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: BTW ORMs offer no abstraction or design benefit. When you import data there are no entities and no behaviour. The *actual* entities are sources, rows, fields, data, transformations. You deal with a *stream* of rows that get transformed on the fly before you store them in their destination. You can handle millions of rows this way with a few MB of RAM. Try doing that with an ORM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, it is definitely not a XY problem, because as I have mentioned in the first sentence of my question - this question has nothing about NHibernate, NHibernate is only used for example. This question is about TPL. Just read my updated question. My *actual problem* is not a problem, but curiousity - **is this possible, is there such syntax, is there a pattern or short solution?**

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes, it's the definition of the XY problem. In order to insert 500K objects you use the database's bulk import features, not try to perform 500K full-wight inserts in parallel. If you target SQL Server, that means SqlBulkCopy. You can *easily* pass objects using eg FastMember's ObjectReader to convert any IEnumerable<T> to a DataReader of T rows and pass it to SqlBulkCopy

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev to put it another way. You only have 500K items. I have 1M+ that I read from various files, parse, convert to objects, modify on the fly and finally store to the DB with TPL Dataflow. The last block uses ObjectReader to adapt batches of my DTOs into DataReaders and send them to the database at maximum speed. I don't need a lot of memory because I *don't* load all of them - I push each object down the pipeline.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev that's why SSIS dataflows perform a lot faster than huge INSERT/UPDATE statements by the way -  in this case I deal with multiple multimillion row tables.

Comment: BTW which database? Different databases have different Bulk copy features, if they have them at all. For example SQL Server's SqlBulkCopy can deal with in-memory objects. MySqlBulkLoader can only send flat files - you have to store the data in a file first. OracleBulkCopy works, but isn't available through a NuGet package

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Regarding this question, I have ABSOLUTELY NO database, NO real project, NO data and NO code except this. I am just curious if **is this possible, is there such syntax, is there a pattern or short solution?**. Abstract from NHibernate and other implementation details, TPL syntax is what I am interested in. Could you please read my question carefully? The question: **is there a TPL syntax which allows you to inject objects into tasks so that one object is only used by one thread at once?**. NHibernate has only been used to give a clear (I guessed so) example.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I already answered that 1) you are asking the wrong question and 2) yes, through TPL Dataflow and 3) You said you have a database `I need to insert them all into database using NHibernate `. I just told you how to store the objects in bulk, even explained how it works for each of the 3 most popular DBs.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev `is this possible, is there such syntax, is there a pattern or short solution?` - no

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This sentence has started from words "For example" and has ended with "Forget about batch insert, I am curious about TPL". Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @Vasek Thank you.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev and 4) you keep asking the wrong question. Saves in parallel will always be slower than batch operations that send multiple statements in a *single* roundtrip. Use NH batching for this. That will still be orders of magnitude slower than *bulk* operations that use minimal locking and logging - if the DB knows this is a bulk operation, it won't log individual inserts, only entire pages

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev the TPL covers a lot of different async/concurrent/parallel **paradigms**. The concrete case matters. Do you need async/await? Parallel operations? PLINQ (not the same as Parallel.)? Pipelines? Stream events? Depends on the actual problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better if everything except the last two edits was removed.

If the question is `Can you pass an object per task (not thread) when using Parallel.`? The answer is : Yes you can, through [any of the overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) that accept local state, ie have a `TLocal` type like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource, TLocal>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

`Parallel.For` doesn't use threads. It partitions the data and creates one task for each partitions. Each task ends up processing all of a partition's data. Typically, `Parallel` uses as many tasks as there are cores. It also uses the *current* thread for processing, which is why it appears to block the current thread. It doesn't, it's begin used to process one of the partitions.

The functions that deal with local data allow you to generate an initial local value and pass it to each `body` invocation. All overloads with local data require the `body` to retun the (possibly modified) data, so `Parallel` itself *doesn't* have to store it. This is essential, since `Parallel.` can terminate and restart tasks. It wouldn't be able to do so easily or efficiently if it had to keep track of local data.

For this particular example, and bypassing the fact that ORMs are unsuitable for bulk operations, especially when dealing with hundreds of thousands of objects, `localInit` should create a new session. `body` should use and return that session while finally, `localFinally` should dispose it.

```
var mySessionFactory
var myData=....;
Parallel.ForEach(
    myData,
    ()=>CreateSession(),
    (record,state,session)=>{
        //process the data etc.
        return session;
    },
    (session)=>session.Dispose()
);
```

Some more warnings though. NH keeps changes in memory until they are flushed and the cache cleared out. This will create memory issues. One solution would be to keep count and flush the data periodically. Instead of a session, the state could be a `(int counter,Session session)` tupple:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    myData,
    ()=>(counter:0,session:CreateSession()),
    (record,state,localData)=>{
        var (counter,session)=localData;
        //process the data etc.
        if (counter % 1000 ==0)
        {
            session.Flush();
            session.Clear();
        }
        return (++counter,session);
    },
    data=>data.session.Dispose()
);
```

A *better* solution would be to batch the objects in advance, so that instead of an `IEnumerable<MyRecord>` the loop would work on `IEnumerable<MyRecord[]>` arrays. In conjuction with batched statements this would reduce the performance penalty imposed by ORMs on bulk operations.

Writing a `Batch` method isn't hard, but [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) already provides one, available as source or a NuGet package :

```
var myBatches=myData.Batch(1000);
Parallel.ForEach(
    myBatches,
    ()=>CreateSession(),
    (records,state,session)=>{

        foreach(var record in records)
        {
            //process the data etc.
            session.Save(record);                
        }
        session.Flush();
        session.Clear();
        return session;
    },
    data=>data.session.Dispose()
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your wide and precise answer, that's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for misguiding you with NHibernate example. I have also updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

The closest solution is to create N threads manually (either with `Task` or `Parallel.For` / `Parallel.ForEach`) and use `ConcurrentQueue` to distribute data thread-safely.

Comment: Posting Vasek's answer from comments as community answer.

Comment: Yes there definitely is. Check the overloads of `ForEach`. There are a lot of overloads that deal with local data. They are easy to spot as they use the generic type `TLocal` for the local data type